# Why am I getting an error in web config in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET and in the web config file get the this error:

> web config section must only appear once per config file

My web config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myCaseLoginEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntity.LoginModel.csdl|res://*/MyEntity.LoginModel.ssdl|res://*/MyEntity.LoginModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=myCase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="myCaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myCase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="CaseManagementConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CaseManagement;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I added this line to that file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Before that I did not have any errors. How can I solve that problem Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because you declarere it twice as self-closing?

Comment: If only error messages would say what was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have section `httpRuntime` twice in your config file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

and

```
<httpRuntime/>
```

Just like it says in the error message that you posted, section must only appear once per config file. So in order to fix the issue remove one of the `httpRuntime` sections and configuration file should be valid.

Comment: you say remove the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />? line?

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi You need to remove one of two lines that I mentioned - either one, or another.